# objective C new method not defined may be the issue

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code in objective-c, with an warning. The posts I reviewed about it seem to imply that it is not a huge issue; it is a method that is automatically created. In my case though, does not give the result if should. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Given that this is one of the first few programs in objective-C I am doing, I like to validate it so I can become familiar with the right syntax. Here is the code:

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <objc/Object.h>
//---------------interface section-------------

@interface Fraction: Object
{
  int numerator;
  int denominator;
}
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
-(void) setDenominator: (int) d;
-(void) print;
@end
//-----------------implementation section-------
@implementation Fraction;
//getters
-(int) numerator
{
  return numerator;
}
-(int) denominator
{
  return denominator;
}
//setters
-(void) setNumerator: (int) num
{
  numerator = num;
}
-(void) setDenominator: (int) denom
{
  denominator = denom;
}
-(void) print
{
  printf("The value of the fraction is %i/%i\n", numerator, denominator);
}
@end
//-----------------program section-------------------------
int main (void)
{
  Fraction *myFract;
  myFract = [Fraction new];
  [myFract setNumerator: 1];
  [myFract setDenominator: 3];

  printf ("The numerator is %i, and the denominator is %i\n", [myFract numerator], [myFract denominator]);
  [myFract print];
  [myFract free];
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the warning message:

```
$ gcc -o fraction fraction.m -I /GNUstep/System/Library/Headers -L /GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lobjc -lgnustep-b
ase -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString
fraction.m: In function 'main':
fraction.m:43:3: warning: 'Fraction' may not respond to '+new' [enabled by default]
fraction.m:43:3: warning: (Messages without a matching method signature [enabled by default]
fraction.m:43:3: warning: will be assumed to return 'id' and accept [enabled by default]
fraction.m:43:3: warning: '...' as arguments.) [enabled by default]
fraction.m:49:3: warning: 'Fraction' may not respond to '-free' [enabled by default]
```

Here is the output:

```
$ ./fraction.exe
The numerator is 0, and the denominator is 0
```

Not sure if it is relevant, but I am using GNUstep to compile it. I don't know of a way to run debug on it. I tried GDB but it did not work. By the way, do I need a Mac environment, if I want to take full advantage of this language's benefits? Are there non-Mac / apple applications of this language?

Comment: There are *some* non Apple-environment applications that are written in Objective-C, but it is very much seen as an Apple technology. The Apple compiler is the gold standard for what the definition of Objective-C is.

Comment: Is there any way to learn the libraries a bit without having to purchase an Apple machine? I love the product; I just don't wanna spend the money right now.

Comment: New Macs are pretty expensive, but you might be able to find a used Mac fairly cheap. If you just want to learn Objective-C, then any Mac that can run OS X should do. It is possible to run OS X on non-Apple hardware, though it's a violation of Apple's software license agreement to do so. Information about how to create a "Hackintosh"is readily-available on the Internet.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I think purchasing a used mini and leveraging a KVM is a great way to get access to one of the best products I know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object` is a deprecated root class. Use `NSObject` instead. Don't call `free`. If you are using manual memory management, use `release`. If you are using ARC, then don't call anything.

`new` doesn't have to be supported by `GNUstep`, so you should use the class `alloc` and `init` pattern.

```
@interface Fraction: NSObject
{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
}
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
-(void) setDenominator: (int) d;
-(void) print;
@end
//-----------------implementation section-------
@implementation Fraction;
//getters
-(int) numerator
{
    return numerator;
}
-(int) denominator
{
    return denominator;
}
//setters
-(void) setNumerator: (int) num
{
    numerator = num;
}
-(void) setDenominator: (int) denom
{
    denominator = denom;
}
-(void) print
{
    printf("The value of the fraction is %i/%i\n", numerator, denominator);
}
@end
//-----------------program section-------------------------
int main (void)
{
    Fraction *myFract = [[Fraction alloc] init];
    [myFract setNumerator: 1];
    [myFract setDenominator: 3];

    printf ("The numerator is %i, and the denominator is %i\n", [myFract numerator], [myFract denominator]);
    [myFract print];
    [myFract release];
    return 0;
}
```

You can also simplify with properties, the following is Obj-C 2.0 syntax with Automatic Reference Counting.

```
@interface Fraction: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) int numerator;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int denominator;

- (void)print;

@end

@implementation Fraction
- (void)print {
   printf("The value of the fraction is %i/%i\n", self.numerator, self.denominator);
}
@end

int main (void)
{
    Fraction *myFract = [[Fraction alloc] init];
    myFract.numerator = 1;
    myFract.denominator = 3;

    printf ("The numerator is %i, and the denominator is %i\n", [myFract numerator], [myFract denominator]);
    [myFract print];
    return 0;
}
```

Even with GNUstep you should use Clang for compilation. GCC just won't do any more.

Comment: I don't think GNUstep supports ARC, though at some point they did support mark/sweep Garbage Collection.

Comment: @MarkBessey It does but with Clang, see http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/ObjC2_FAQ

Comment: Oh, cool. It has been quite a while since I tried to do anything with GNUstep.

Comment: Default GNU step does not like NSObject. I guess I'll try clang. I know very little about clang; just so I know I am downloading the right tool, can someone give me the url? fraction.m:2:26: fatal error: objc/NSObject.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated. I looked in the objc folder of gnustep, I don't see a NSObject file.

Comment: @maverick I am pretty sure you will have to import `Foundation` for `NSObject` (http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/Reference/NSObject.html). Clang is needed for ARC, definitely but you can live without that.